# Is Lucene.net abandoned?

Tags: lucene.net

I'm currently testing Lucene.Net, and it's perfect for my needs but I've seen  [this recent post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-lucene-net-dev/201010.mbox/browser) in the dev mailing list (with no answers)...
Do you think it's unsafe to start developping with this library ? 
I thought it was widespread used ?

Comment: Lucene is used in a variety of projects, but that is in no way automatically true also for Lucene .NET

Comment: Its always lagged behind a bit, but I didn't know the situation got that bad . ..

Comment: It is 2014, the last update was almost 2 years ago, 10/2012, the Java version got updated a couple of days ago, I know lucene.net is in a usable state, but is it abandoned now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know Lucene.NET is used for RavenDB, so it should be in pretty good shape.

Also, it depends on what do you mean by "unsafe". It is hard to guarantee any OSS project will never stop, so all of them are inherently "unsafe". Same is actually true for commercial projects.

Lucene.NET seems to be a reliable project at current point (I used it in small project, so I can not guarantee that, but RavenDB seems to do just fine), so even if new development stops, it should still be possible to rely on it.

I think it all depends on longevity of your project, on your readiness to fix any issues in Lucene (if they arise), and on requirements of the project owners.

Comment: You're right about RavenDB using it, in fact this issue was just discussed on the mailing list, see http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/a32bda2d4383c98f

Comment: Stackoverflow use it as well.  So it should continue to be developed by one of these major players